# Genearate mutiple log files using log4j

Tags: java, log4j, java.util.logging

how to generate Multiple log files using log 4j for single application.
Here i want to generate 2 log file.so can You please add some some sample example for this one.I tried with this one and it genearating 2nd log file,but not able to open that file.Can You please suggest me?

```
log.dir=C:/Migration/logs/Export&ImportLogs_${current.date}.csv
rrd.dir=${log.dir}/rrd
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log.dir}
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=info
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=2
```

Comment: Here i am able to genearate,but thing is that if i want to create another log file with different name using this properties,it is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java configure two loggers

```
static final Logger log1= Logger.getLogger("log1");
static final Logger log2= Logger.getLogger("log2");
```

In log4j.properties, add following:

```
log4j.category.log1=INFO, logger1
log4j.additivity.log1=false

log4j.category.log2=DEBUG, logger2
log4j.additivity.log2=false

log4j.appender.logger1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.logger1.File=log1.log
log4j.appender.logger1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logger1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j.appender.logger2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.logger2.File=log2.log
log4j.appender.logger2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logger2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

log4j.category property can be used to log from code in a specific package to a different log file.

```
log4j.category.com.abc.def = INFO , file2   
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.file.File=a.log  
log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8  
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout    
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd

log4j.appender.file2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.file2.File=b.log     
log4j.appender.file2.encoding=UTF-8     
log4j.appender.file2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.file2.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```